# VBA Print Parentheses Around Value

Tags: excel, vba

This is pretty basic, but I want enter a Double value into a cell, but I want it to be formatted in between parentheses. It works when the value is one digit, however with anymore the parentheses don't appear around the value.

If I'm correct, formatting parentheses should occur as such:

```
Cells(NextRun, 9) = "(" & sagdif & ")"
```

Comment: If you want the cell contents to actually contain parentheses, change the cell's format to Text first. If you want it to just appear as a number in parentheses, set an [appropriate financial format](https://superuser.com/q/998866/52365) and do not try to add parentheses manually.

Comment: You're saying that the I should just change the cells format in the actual worksheet rather than doing it in vba? Btw, the scope of what I'm trying to accomplish is a UserForm, where an individual will put the data into a textbox and that will be populated into a cell automatically.

Comment: `I should just change the cells format in the actual worksheet` - yes.

Comment: Changing the format is much preferred than "adding formatting via formula".  This is because if you ever need to use that information in a formula/analysis, you aren't being thrown off by errant parenthesis which exist as part of the data itself.